# Adding onclick event on all links on my website

Tags: html, drupal, onclick

I need to apply this line:

```
target="_blank" onclick="exoMobilePop();"
```

To all links on my Drupal 7 website.
Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need this functionality on links and not on the whole document you can go with this solution.

```
  ...
  <script>
    (function() {
      var linksOnPage = document.querySelectorAll("a");
      var link = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < linksOnPage.length; i++) {
        link = linksOnPage[i];
        link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        link.addEventListener("click", function(e){
          exoMobilePop();  
        });
      }
    })();
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

But be careful. This will address literally every link on your page. Including administrative links, menu items, etc. If it's not desired, you can replace "a" with a more specific selector.

Comment: If you can edit the page template, you can add it to the very end of the HTML code.

But it's more elegant to save it as an external script and include it at the end of the document <script src="myJsFile.js"></script> as Travis suggested. In this case you have to copy only this part:

function() {...})();

Put it into a separate file and include it via <script> tag.

Comment: (Updated the example with HTML parts to help locating the right spot in the template)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`<base>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base). The `target` attribute specifies the default target for all hyperlinks and forms in the page. Place the tag in the `<head>` section.

> **Note:** This attribute can be overridden by using the target attribute for each hyperlink/form (if needed).

```
<head>
...
<base target="_blank">
...
</head>
```

---

Use JavaScript (or jQuery) to handle and reroute the `click` events. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/5jLo4u5y/5/)

**JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    // e.preventDefault(); // Prevent a link from following the URL
    exoMobilePop(); 
});
```

**jQuery**

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function (e) {
    // e.preventDefault(); // Prevent a link from following the URL
    exoMobilePop();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not work for me. I've just try to put this line in head section:

Comment: Where to put this code?    document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    exoMobilePop();  
});

Comment: @user2337504 - I just updated my answer. I was too hopeful about what I thought the `base` tag could do. Add the JS to take care of the rest.

Comment: @user2337504 - depends...but if you have multiple pages you can save this in an external .js file and link it e.g. `<script src="myJsFile.js"></script>` or just put it before your closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: I've try to make external js file and put this line in the head section <script src="myJsFile.js"></script> . Now my links doesn't clickable at all.

Comment: @user2337504 - remove `e.preventDefault();` and the links will behave normally, but also run the `exoMobilePop();` function

Comment: Try to delete e.preventDefault(); but links are still doesn't clickable.

Comment: @user2337504  - Provide your code so I can help you further. If you have `<base target="_blank">` in the `<head>` and correctly link one of the two scripts provided, then... **1.** the URL will open in a new tab **2.** the `exoMobilePop();` function will execute.